# cairo and librsvg statically linked with "dll.a" don't run outside mingw

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I found this [example](https://github.com/songulabuzar/librsvg-minimal-example) over the internet, on how to use librsvg, it compiles on mingw, and it runs, but it does not run outside mingw context. (For example going to explorer and double clicking the file).
The error is:

```
the code execution cannot proceed because librsvg-2-2.dll was not found. reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
the code execution cannot proceed because libcairo-2.dll was not found. reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

Now, I want to run this code outside mingw, but it doesn't find the cairo and librsvg dlls, (I have no .dlls only .dll.a files), running it inside mingw works perfectly.
These are my compilation flags. (I changed the name from main.c to main.cpp)

How can I make this code run, in this case?

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o -I/mingw64/include/librsvg-2.0 -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
g++ main.o -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread /mingw64/lib/libcairo.dll.a /mingw64/lib/librsvg-2.dll.a -o main.exe
```

Comment: The dlls should be in the `bin` folder. The `dll.a` files are in the lib folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I just figured out that the name is different, first it appends a "-2" to end of the filename, is it possible to bundle the dlls with the executable? Or do I have to copy and paste them?

Comment: ***is it possible to bundle the dlls with the executable?*** Use a program like NSIS to create an installer that installs your software on other PCs like most commercial applications do: [https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download)

Comment: ***Or do I have to copy and paste them?*** Depends on how you are building. With CMake you can write a script to do this for you. You could also do that in a Makefile. Although if you just want to run your program on your PC by clicking in the file explorer all you have to do is to put the bin folder in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: This Microsoft document tells you how and where your OS looks for dependent dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)